# User enabled status is checked before authentication - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my loadByUserName() method I find the user by mail. Currently my User class implements UserDetails with isEnabled() method to check if a user is enabled or not. However, this enabled flag is checked before authentication and this way anybody can find out whether another user's account is enabled or not, no matter what password is used. Is there a way to check the enabled flag after authentication?

My User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Column(name = "ativo")
    private Boolean ativo;

    //... some attributes, getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        if(this.ativo){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My loadUserByUsername() method:

```
@Override
public User loadUserByUsername(String mail) {
    List<User> users = manager.findUserByMail(String mail);

    if (pessoas.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("User not found!");
    } 
    return users.get(0);
}
```

I changed the default message in case of bad credential or user disabled:

messages.properties:

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials = Mail/Password is incorrect!
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled = User disabled!
```

Comment: Hi there, it would be better if you show us your current running code/method because there is no point of telling us your method name and we dont know what the code is about or is the code running well. So there would be some recommendations from others and it would help other people especially regarding this particular field in the future. Thanks

Comment: Hi! I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to simply change the message to be the same for both. Something like **Unknown username/password**. Regardless of the fact if it is enabled or not. Telling them it is also a kind of security breach. On a different note your `loadByUsername` method is flawed (it doesn't follow the contract!). It should throw a `UsernameNotFound` exception not a plain `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer this question in a way that you can utilize not only in this case, but also in other simillar situation.

How does the user of your application understand what happened in your code? He knows nothing about your code but we (as developers) are the ones who informed them what happened behined the scene and which method executed first using message.properties.

If you don't inform them, they don't have any way to know which method executed first. so you can change both properties to the same message to something like 'password is incorrect'.

This is exactly what is happening in Linux operating system when you want to login with username that dosn't exist linux don't tell you that the user does not exist, even if the user does not exist it let you to enter password and after that inform you that the password is incorrect. Because Generally we should not give extra information to people who are doing malicious action. Generaly this kind of information is very helpfull for developer and for monitoring purposes. so you should find a way to log this kind of information for future use, but not show them to the user.